# Copy object from one user profile to another in django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am finding a lot of answers on this question but not able to to figure out how to apply this to my issue.

I have a wishlist for each user and many users can have the same wish. What I want to do is if David has a pepsi on it list the pepsi = product. And Michelle wants to add that to her list. I want to be able to to copy and save  the product ie pepsi  save it as a vairable so i can add it to the database with Michelles user name so now i have to database entries with pepsi but different users. I do not want michelle to have to enter the product but just click the button to add it.  I belive if I modify my create function I could do this. I just dont know what to use  to get the product into the model of the specfic one they clicked.

views
    def edit(request, id):

```
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        Myblackbelt.objects.filter(what would i put here to pull the current product)

    return redirect ('blackbelt:index')

def create(request):

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        secret_id = User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id']) 
        viewsResponse = Myblackbelt.objects.add_product(request.POST, secret_id) 

    return redirect ('blackbelt:index')

model

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from ..logReg.models import User


class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def add_product(self, postData, user): 
        product = postData.get('product', None) 
        if product is not None and user: 
            Myblackbelt = self.create(product=product, creator=user)

    def add_wish(self, postData, user): 
        pass





class Myblackbelt(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    loguser = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='loguser')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator')


    objects = ProductManager()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django you can copy an object by retrieving it from the database, clearing the id and calling the save method. In your case that would look like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
    product = Myblackbelt.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    product.pk = None
    product.creator = request.user
    product.save()
```